# Anchor tag in form label using Html.LabelFor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, label

I would like to accomplish something like

```
<label for="AgreedToTherms">
I agree to the <a href="therms-and-conditions">Therms and conditions</a>
</label>
```

Is this allowed according to html standards?
Using the standard Html helper in a view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgreedToTherms)
```

I tried to use add the html inside the labeltext but this text gets html encoded

Comment: you can wrap the encoded html in @Html.Raw() to convert it back to usable html code...

Answer (score 11):

You can do this way:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
    Html.LabelFor(m=>m.AgreedToTherms).ToString()))
```

(OR)

```
@Html.Raw(@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
    Html.LabelFor(m=>m.AgreedToTherms).ToString()))
```

Comment: Not sure if this is actually a valid answer now, at least not with today's browsers since clicking on a label should put focus on the associated input control?